# Stopping a dynamically created Soundcloud oEmbed player when closing a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud, oembed

I am working on a webapp that allows people to share links from Soundcloud by copying and pasting the URL.  Then the webapp generates a running list of people, allowing users to open a modal that loads the a Soundcloud player (via SC.oEmbed).  The URL is derived from the  element that opens up the modal.  So SC.oEmbed opens up the URL found within the href attribute.

I have everything working great, except that when the modal is closed the music keeps playing.

There doesn't seem to be a stop() or pause() function associated with this player like there is with the Widget player.  The only solution I have found is upon close to have SC.oEmbed open up another random soundcloud link but with auto_play off.  This works but seems really inelegant and a waste of resources.  There must be a better way no? Oh, and I'm using Twitter Bootstrap too.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    SC.initialize({
  client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
});

    $("a[data-target='#myModal']").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); /* makes sure <a> link doesn't actually open new window */
            var url = this.href; // gets Soundcloud URL from href in <a> element
            SC.oEmbed(url, { auto_play: false }, document.getElementById("audio_1_body"));
    });

/* this part below is what I want to improve -- loading up a random track, just to stop playing of track that was loaded in the modal */

    $("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
           url = "https://soundcloud.com/the-deep-dark-woods/sugar-mama-1"; 
           SC.oEmbed(url, { auto_play: false },       document.getElementById("audio_1_body")); //this last part is what I want to improve
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Does not seem that there is a way to do so from SC JS SDK.

Best you can do is to delete SC iframe:

```js
$('#audio_1_body').html('')
```